# How to migrate Mage1 configurable products to Mage2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, import

I have huge problems migrating configurable products from Mage1 to Mage2. Whats the best way to copy ALL products (including configureable and bundle products) to Mage2? The basic Export and Import seem to be underpowered...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider using Magento's official data migration tool: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html as using standard data export/import between the 2 systems will not work (without major reworking of the exported files) as the formats are not compatible and some major changes have been made to how configurable products work between the 2 versions.